# Refactor/Optimize Java code to get HostNameVerifier

Tags: java, optimization, java-8, refactoring

I have below java class which checks if the `instance` is not blank and matches `dev`/`qa`/`stg`/`staging`/`prod` and `hostnameVerification` is `true` then `getHostnameVerifierForInstance` returns a customized `HostnameVerifier`

```
public class SSLConfig {
    private static final String PROD_INSTANCE = "Prod";
    private static final String STG_INSTANCE1 = "Staging";
    private static final String STG_INSTANCE2 = "Stg";
    private static final String QA_INSTANCE = "QA";
    private static final String DEV_INSTANCE = "DEV";

     private static HostnameVerifier getHostnameVerifierForInstance(String instance, String hostnameVerification) {
        LOGGER.info("HostnameVerifier For Instance = {}, hostnameVerification = {}",instance,hostnameVerification);
        HostnameVerifier hostnameVerifier = new HostnameVerifier() {
            public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {
                return true;
            }
        };
        if(StringUtils.isNotBlank(instance)) {
            if ((instance.trim().toLowerCase().startsWith(PROD_INSTANCE.toLowerCase()) || instance.trim().toLowerCase().startsWith(STG_INSTANCE1.toLowerCase()) || instance.trim().toLowerCase().startsWith(STG_INSTANCE2.toLowerCase()) || instance.trim().toLowerCase().startsWith(QA_INSTANCE.toLowerCase()) || instance.trim().toLowerCase().startsWith(DEV_INSTANCE.toLowerCase())) && StringUtils.isNotBlank(hostnameVerification) && hostnameVerification.trim().toLowerCase().equalsIgnoreCase("true")) {
                hostnameVerifier = new HostnameVerifier() {
                    public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {
                        DefaultHostnameVerifier verifier = new DefaultHostnameVerifier();
                        return verifier.verify(hostname, session);
                    }
                };
            }
        }
        return hostnameVerifier;
    }
}
```

I am wondering Can this method be refactored/improved to a better version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your code after refactoring should be like this:

```
public class SSLConfig {
    private static final String PROD_INSTANCE = "Prod";
    private static final String STG_INSTANCE1 = "Staging";
    private static final String STG_INSTANCE2 = "Stg";
    private static final String QA_INSTANCE = "QA";
    private static final String DEV_INSTANCE = "DEV";

    private static HostnameVerifier getHostnameVerifierForInstance(String instance,
                                                                   String enabled){
        return Boolean.parseBoolean(enabled)&&reject(instance) ? denyAll() 
                : permitAll();
    }

    private static boolean reject(String instance) {
        return rejections().anyMatch(instance.trim().toLowerCase()::startsWith);
    }

    private static Stream<String> rejections() {
        return Stream.of(PROD_INSTANCE, STG_INSTANCE1,
                STG_INSTANCE2, QA_INSTANCE, DEV_INSTANCE).map(String::toLowerCase);
    }

    private static HostnameVerifier denyAll() {
        return (hostname, session) -> false;
    }

    private static HostnameVerifier permitAll() {
        return (hostname, session) -> true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Does `Boolean.parseBoolean()` throw exception if `enabled` is empty?

Comment: @RanPaul it  return `false` rather than throw exception if enabled is empty. you can write some tests to verify or see the source code directly.

Comment: Thanks also, `denyAll` is not supposed to return false it should return `return new HostnameVerifier() {
            public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {
                DefaultHostnameVerifier verifier = new DefaultHostnameVerifier();
                return verifier.verify(hostname, session);
            }
        };`

Comment: @RanPaul ^_^, you can rename the methods after you understand the problem domain, but I think you want to deny all request since I see you use the `DefaultHostnameVerifier` directly .